# Impossible to import local dependency in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Example :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.codindf</groupId>
      <artifactId>morpion</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This file is present on my .m2 directory and have a good structure

Have you a solution ? for this really basic problem ...

[image]

This is my parameters

[image]

---

---

---

[image]

---

Comment: What do you mean, impossible?  What happens when you try?  Is there some kind of error?  (Although I have a different version of IntelliJ from you, I've never had any trouble getting this to work).

Comment: com.codindf:morpion:jar:1.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)

Comment: Apparently ItelliJ tell maven to search dependency on maven central, BUT this dependency is on my own repo on [user]/.m2 standrad directory directory

Comment: Have you got your local repository listed in the Maven settings?  (File | Settings | Build,Execution,Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories)?  And is it listed above or below Maven Central?

Comment: yes like you can watch below on screenshot

Comment: OK, did you try swapping the entries on the Repositories page over, so that IntelliJ checks the local repository first?

Comment: The given dependency simply does not exist in central repository. So your build can't be successful.  And what does `This file is present on my .m2 directory and have a good structure` mean?

Comment: By default, normal maven process is to check **local repository first** to avoid network tranfert, and then if resources is not found find it to central maven
You can see the address of local repository on screen below
not all dependencies reside on central maven, dude ;-)

Comment: Any other questions ?...

Answer (score 0):

I aplogize to all pepole try to answer to my post.
I made a mistake in the name of groupId
I wrote :

```
<groupId>com.codindf</groupId>
```

but the real name is :

```
<groupId>com.codingf</groupId>
```

Sorry to All !